# Entity Framework 6 auto compiled queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a query that is taking a bit of time on the first execution. All subsequent executions are super fast (even with different data). I believe the first execution EF is auto compiling the query (building the query plan, blah blah blah) and the second call is using the compiled version. Which is fine, except for the first user. That poor sap is screwed. On a bad day, the EF execution will be 2 minutes (with 71ms actually talking to SQL Server - verified with SQL Server Profiler.)

I've gone ahead and have precompiled the views, which did shave some time off the initial caching.

Basically the query looks a little something like this

```
dataSource.Component
    .Include(t => t.Table1)
    ... 37 tables later ...
    .Include(t => t.Table38)
    .Where(n=>n.Id == id).First()
```

Now I can't go a fiddling around with the data model. But for background, basically each table is a 'Form.'

The SQL Server Profiler output is basically a big UNION with the tables but the execution is very fast so I don't think the problem is the table layout/keys...

Other than warming EF on startup, I am hoping I am missing something basic? It seems like the pipeline for compiling the query is pretty black box? Is there a way to hook into the query prep process to see whats going on? (Maybe something less drastic than grabbing the source.. :)

Comment: Do you really need to include 35+ tables?  You would probably be best served writing straight sql; and may be worth considering creating a view to query against.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the project is too far along to just do that.  Plus, the actual SQL execution is excellent, it's just this EF compile that is slow.  So creating a wide view with 100+ columns may actually put us back in the same spot.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options in my opinion:

1. Use the known sqlQuery and just for this one query execute it as raw sql through your DbContext as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx):

   ```
   datasource.Component.SqlQuery("...").ToList();
   ```
2. You can use a delegate which returns an `IQueryable` to be able to precompile your expression:

   ```
   public static Func<MyContext,int,IQueryable<Component>> CompiledQuery = (ctx,id) => 
          ctx.Include(c => c.Table1)
             .Include(c => c.Table2)
             ...
             .Include(c => c.Table38)
             .Where(n => n.Id == id);
   ```

   Then in your code you can use `Invoke` to use the query:

   ```
   using(var datasource = new MyContext())
   {
       var result = CompiledQuery.Invoke(datasource,2).ToList();
   }
   ```

The second option is probably best for you. Since .NET 4.5 all your queries are cached as a Func as described above automatically which explains why it runs smoothly the second time. Creating the delegate manually should resolved your issue the first time you run the query.

Comment: I think, problem is NOT in not compiled query. I bet, 90% of time is objects materialization

Comment: Except that this does not speed up the compilation any more. It only moves the compilation time to the constructor. Which in the case of ASP.Net could be the first run....>_<

Comment: @Backs You sir, should read the question again. The first execution of the query is slow. Subsequent calls are fast.

Comment: @Aron Then his only option is calling a stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  Option 1 is interesting but kinda negates the value prop of EF.  If I were to do that, I might as well just do the whole thing in ADO.Net.  We've bought into the promise of EF.  :)

I'll give option 2 a go, but compiled queries require the ObjectContext, not the DbContext, correct?  It's worth a shot though, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: So doing the invoke doesn't help, first hit slow.
I'm just going to develop an attribute that I can mark slow Get methods and have some startup code to find all methods with that attribute and run them.  Then hope they don't reach the query plan limit and get cycled out. :)  (3.2.2      Cache eviction algorithm - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#_Query_Plan_Caching)

Comment: Hi guys, I have the same issue but I can not use a delegate (2 option suggested) to return the Iqueryable because I select particular fields of my query in a anonymous type. Any idea how to achieve it?